# Word 2013 form tab issue

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, docx

I will make a formular in word. The user should be able to tab trough the form by keyboard. The use of arrow keys will be a nice goody but is not necessary. I created a simple sample form looks like so:

[image: Sample]

I use the current form elements (no legacy ones) in the developer bar on word 2013.

[image: Form Items]

My goal is to be able to tab with the tab-key trough the form only the form fields. Like shown in the following picture.

[image: Goal Tab order]

If you use the tab-key in the form the order looks like following: 
[image]

The surrounding table will included in the tab order and at the end of the table it will sometimes added a new row. That is not suitable for a form.

So I tried to protect the form to >only fillout form<. That is much better, but there are the following issues:

1. First if a text field is used a tab makes a tab inside the textfield
2. Tabbing on checkboxes is very weird every second box will be over
   tabed and after selection the next box will be marked.

I there a way to generate a tabable form in word 2013?

Comment: did you try to set the tab order in the object's properties? But I think Word is not a good tool for creating interactive form

Comment: I know that word is not the best tool for interactive forms, But there are constrains that not allow PDF or webapplication. I tried to change the order but the table will still triggered by tabes and add at the ende a empty row.